# Crystal Reports: Suppressing a field conditionally according to group name in current page

Tags: crystal-reports, suppress, suppression

I have a group named: "Group #1 Name" and as you know when viewing the report at the first page in Group 1 section we see the title of group but this is not appears in next page till we navigate to next group.
Now i want to display the current Group Title navigating by user in the header of page to help user know currently is in witch group( for ex: if group name is name of countries, Products in Country "A" is continued in next page and other next pages and we vant see these products country).

I copied my "Group #1 Name" and put it on the page header this working but there is a problem:
when navigating the report from viewer and when we see the next group(Ex: Country B) at the header the value is still Country A and if you continue navigatin to the next page it will be correct.
this is my Q:
How Can I Suppress The header field According to the Group Name?
cleary I want to Suppress Field that shows Country A in the header when The Group Country B is Displaying In the Current Page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest right-clicking on the relevant Group in the Designer, selecting Group Options, and then checking Show Group Header On Each Page. No need to mess about with putting Group #1 Name in the page header. If you want it to appear as if it's in the page header, you can investigate the Underlay Following Section option.

Comment: TNX CodeByMoonlight! it working nice but I want ato Display Group Name in another Format when we are in detail Pages!

Comment: What do you mean by detail pages? The detail section? Just use a separate Formula Field.

Comment: Thank you. Now I have another Question Under above Question and it is relevant. How Can I Find Page Number of a Specific Member in a group Name? Can I reach that? EX: You know we have Group name 1 and this group has 5 Items(A,B,C,D,E) can I get page Number for Item B?
Can You Help me?

Comment: That partly depends on where you want to use the page number information. If it's on the last page of the report, then you can use a formula array and runtime formulas. If it's on the first...then it's often impossible.
You'll get answers easier if you start a new post on StackOVerflow, as only people who commented here will get notified of your queries here.

Answer (score 1):

You want to go to the *group expert*, select the group, and check the option to *repeat group header on each page*. It will repeat the group header as long as it has a details section in the page. It will not repeat the header if it is only the footer being displayed.